# Align text and images on buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place text under an image on my button. I am using the following code to display the image on the left, and the text on the right.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/mango"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mango"
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
android:text="@string/mango_button"
android:padding="15dp"
android:onClick="fruit" />
```

I understand that the line:

```
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

Makes this work - but I don't really understand how. I'd like to know if I can make the image stick to the top, and the text be placed below it in the same style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm blind. The line

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mango"
```

is where I need to make the changes - not the gravity.

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/mango"
```

gives me what I want, pretty much.